# Sourcing a Degas? quotation

Tags: traduction, histoire, questions

This is the English version of the quotation attributed to Degas:

> Conversation in real life is full of half-finished sentences and overlapping talk. Why shouldn't painting be too?

A direct translation with Google gives:

> La conversation dans la vie réelle est pleine de phrases à moitié terminées et de discours qui se chevauchent. Pourquoi ne pas peindre aussi?

A slightly earlier version of the quote comes from [Rothenstein](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=mPL0csRfbn0C&q=%22And%20was%20not%20the%20same%20true%20of%20appearance%3F%22&dq=%22And%20was%20not%20the%20same%20true%20of%20appearance%3F%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y):

> Conversation in real life was full of half-finished sentences and overlapping talk. And was not the same true of appearance?

Taking this to [Google (Fr.)](https://www.google.fr/search?safe=strict&glp=1&adtest=on&hl=FR&biw=1247&bih=605&tbm=bks&ei=gUGFW5rMLc-g-Qbkl4OICw&q=%22Degas%22%20La%20conversation%20dans%20la%20vie%20r%C3%A9elle%20est%20pleine%20de%20phrases%20%C3%A0%20moiti%C3%A9%20termin%C3%A9es%20et%20de%20discours%20qui%20se%20chevauchent.%20Pourquoi%20ne%20pas%20peindre%20aussi&oq=%22Degas%22%20La%20conversation%20dans%20la%20vie%20r%C3%A9elle%20est%20pleine%20de%20phrases%20%C3%A0%20moiti%C3%A9%20termin%C3%A9es%20et%20de%20discours%20qui%20se%20chevauchent.%20Pourquoi%20ne%20pas%20peindre%20aussi&gs_l=psy-ab.3...408882.410117.0.412077.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.fzV2m_MiQM4) produces nothing approaching the match, as does neither selected word combinations of the phrase. There is also a possibility it may either not be from Degas or the original translation from the French had lost something.
A solution to the question would include a possible alternative translation either

- From the French original to a different English version.
  or
- From the above phrase to a closer fitting French version.

Comment: `Why shouldn't painting be too?` should be translated as `pourquoi n'en serait-il pas de même pour la peinture?` 
don't know if this will throw results though, I will try to find what you are looking for ;)

Comment: @Flying_whale: Thanks. Found a slightly different version and added it to the above as well

Comment: It's looking more and more like a Benicka quote. In the [previous lines](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=mPL0csRfbn0C&dq=Changing+only+the+details+was+rather+like+introducing&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22a+play+that+was+still+in+verse+and+meant+to+be+acted+in+the+grand+manner%22) there is no indication of a pending citation from Degas.

Comment: Actually the book is by [Rothenstein](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4533264-great-modern-masters). Error in Google Books. Benicka edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too knowledgeable about painting, or at least not enough to know if this makes sense, but I found out some paintings from Degas called "[La conversation]" (= The discussion). You could easily find some of these just by googling it, but here's [a page where you can see it for now](http://www.artnet.com/artists/edgar-degas/la-conversation-a-19tNgZOQqmEIMhetk8Xz-A2)

By the look of it, it may seem unfinished. And I think that may be the source of this sentence: explaining that painting. Therefore I would translate :

> La conversation dans la vie réelle est pleine de phrases à moitié terminées et de discours qui se chevauchent. Pourquoi en serait-il autrement de la peinture ?

Comment: Ce que je pense ne pas convenir dans votre choix (Pourquoi en serait-il autrement de la peinture?) c'est que la forme utilisée donne l'idée qu'est soulevée la question de la possibilité que l'art tout entier soit passible d'une conformation à un modèle, le modèle de ce qui est avancé comme étant la conversation courante (contestable). C'est très vrai, peut-être la plus grand partie de la conversation courante n'existe que selon le modèle avancé, cependant ce n'est qu'un mode;  en peinture les genres bien établie n'ont rien à devoir au modèle "coup de hache"; (continué)

Comment: C'est pourquoi il me semble approprié dans ce présent contexte de se restreindre à l'idée de genre ; « Pourquoi n'en serait-il pas de même pour un nouveau genre dans le domaine de la peinture ? » ou quelque chose de cette sorte me parait être un plus souhaitable choix. PS Lorsque je dis que les genres établis n'ont rien à devoir au modèle ce n'est probablement pas entièrement exact, la peinture moderne doit déjà offrir des exemples, même si pas entièrement typiques de ce qui est envisagé.

Comment: Votre proposition implique il me semble une forte extrapolation de ce qu'a voulu dire l'auteur par rapport à la phrase en anglais...

Comment: Je fais le même reproche à la version anglaise; on comprend bien sûr ce qui est dit: il n'est pas question de s'attarder sûr l'interprétation  que toute la peinture est à revoir et à re-concevoir selon le modèle de la conversation, Seulement c'est une impression désagréable que les deux langues laisse dans mon esprit et l'approximation ne me satisfait pas (si concise). Je ne crois pas extrapoler, l'auteur parle bien de  *toute* la conversation;  plutôt,  je ne peut pas approximer à partir du tout une de ses parties. Différence entre « de la » et « en » pour vous?@Laurent S